# regex to replace a word in a block in a file?

Tags: files, regular-expression, replace, sublime-text

If I have:

```
<Directory />
 words
 allow
 bus
</Directory>
```

Is there a regex that can replace allow with something else and keep the other words and the block intact?

So it should look like:

```
<Directory />
 words
 not
 bus
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Directory />
 words
 bus
</Directory>
```

because I will replace the word with something else or take it out. I've tried a regex like this:

```
(<Directory />(\s|\w|\n)+)allow((\s|\n|\w)+</Directory>)
```

and replace it with `\1\n not \2`, but it replaces allow and deletes the second half of the block which I don't want.

So is there a regex that can replace a word in a block and keep the block intact?

Comment: in your case the replacemente string should be `\1 not \3`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your particular issue, a simple `sed` can achieve what you're showing:

```
$ sed 's/\ballow\b/not/g' afile
<Directory />
 words
 not
 bus
```

The `\b` guards so that we're only replacing words, such as `allow`, with the string `not`. If you want to delete lines that contain the string `allow` you can use `sed` to do that as well:

```
$ sed '/\ballow\b/d' afile
<Directory />
 words
 bus
</Directory>
```